# Fetch column as a list of values with Psycopg2

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

Trying to use psycopg2 for extracting tables and columns from PostgreSQL database and tried the below code:

```py
def execute_sql(sql):
    """
        Execute a query and commits
        :param sql:
        :return:
        """
    conn_info = get_connection_info()
    print(conn_info)
    print('this is conn info above')
    with psycopg2.connect(**conn_info) as connection:
        cur = connection.cursor(cursor_factory=psycopg2.extras.RealDictCursor)
        cur.execute(sql)
        rtn_val = cur.fetchall()
    return rtn_val
```

The output for the SQL which I'm giving coming out as:

```
[RealDictRow([('table_name', 'pg_statistic')]), RealDictRow([('table_name', 'pg_foreign_table')]), RealDictRow([('table_name', 'pg_authid')]), RealDictRow([('table_name', 'pg_shadow')]), RealDictRow([('table_name', 'pg_roles')])]
```

But just want the output as:

```
['pg_statistic','pg_foreign_table', 'pg_authid', 'pg_shadow', 'pg_roles']
```

Comment: Remove `cursor_factory=psycopg2.extras.RealDictCursor`

Comment: Just be aware that will be a tuple not a list.

Comment: These are the options you have:https://www.psycopg.org/docs/extras.html#connection-and-cursor-subclasses. You will need to adapt to what is output so for this case: [row[0] for row in rtn_val]

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like:

````
rtn_val = cur.fetchall()

table_list = [row["table_name"] for row in rtn_val]
```
````

Comment: And you know what that is so you can make the list comprehension dynamic also. Work with what you have, not what you wish for.